# On boundary term of Einstein-Hilbert action

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, boundary-terms

The boundary term of Einstein-Hilbert action can be  written as:

\begin{equation}
\int_Vd^dx\sqrt{|g|} \nabla_{\mu}v^{\mu}=\int_{\partial V}d\Sigma_{\mu}v^{\mu}
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
v^{\mu}=\nabla^{\beta}\delta g_{\alpha \beta}g^{\mu\alpha}-\nabla^{\mu}\delta g_{\alpha\beta}g^{\alpha\beta}.
\end{equation}

Now, i know how to compute $n_{\mu}v^{\mu}$ in order to write the Gibbons-Hawking-York (GHY) term: in this computation the first part of $v^{\mu}$ goes away and we obtain $-n^{\mu}h^{\alpha\beta}\nabla_{\mu}\delta g_{\alpha\beta}$. But, as i can show that the second part is nonzero just by mention that $\nabla^{\mu}$ contracts with $n_{\mu}$, how to show that the first part is zero with similar argument?

Comment: Why do you say that the first part of $v^\mu$ goes away?

Comment: You can rewrite $n_{\mu}v^{\mu}=n^{\mu}(h^{\alpha\beta}+\epsilon n^{\alpha}n^{\beta})(\nabla_{\beta}\delta g_{\mu\alpha}-\nabla_{\mu}\delta g_{\alpha\beta})$. The term $n^{\alpha}n^{\beta}$ cencels by symmetry, and the transverse metric contracts with $\nabla_{\beta}$ and so cancels the first term. Now, the fact that the first term goes away when contracting with $n_{\mu}$ means that it is purely tangent to the boundary. So, i was asking if there was a naive way to say that it is tangent, maybe merely saying that the divergence is tangent, or that i can use stokes (again)?

Answer (score 0):

The Hilbert-Einstein action is

\begin{equation}
S_{EH}=\int_{M} d^4x\sqrt{|g|}R
\end{equation}

where $M$ is the manifold of integration, $g$ is the metric and $R$ is the trace of the curvature tensor.The variation of the action yields

\begin{equation}
\delta S_{EH}=-\int_M d^4x\sqrt{|g|}\Big[G^{\mu\nu}\Big]\delta g_{\mu\nu}+\int d^4x\sqrt{|g|}\nabla_\mu v^\mu
\end{equation}

where $v^\mu$ is the term you described, given by

\begin{equation}
v^\mu = \nabla^\beta \delta g_{\alpha \beta }g^{\alpha \mu}-\nabla^\mu \delta _{\alpha\beta }g^{\alpha\beta }
\end{equation}

The problem is that we can fix $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ but not also $\nabla_\alpha  \delta g_{\mu \nu}$. The solution is to add a boundary term to the action, called the GHY boundary term

\begin{equation}
S=S_{EH}+S_{GHY}
\end{equation}

where the new term is

\begin{equation}
S_{GHY}=2\int_{\partial M} d^3x\sqrt{|\gamma|}K
\end{equation}

where $K$ is the trace of the induced curvature $K_{\mu\nu}$ on the boundary $\partial M$,which has an induced metric $\gamma_{\mu\nu}$. The variation of this new action doesn't add anything to the equations of motion, but it adds a term that exactly cancels $v^\mu$.

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, since the variation of the GHY action exactly cancels $v^\mu$, not just a part of it.

Comment: I answered you in the comment of the post